# Not able to retrieve roles from GenericIdentity

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, .net-security

I am setting up a `GenericPrincipal` adding a `GenericIdentity` & roles to it, but when I try to retrieve roles from it I am getting nothing. However, if I call `Principal.IsInRole`, it returns the correct value.

What am I missing?

> **Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uan3ru

```cs
var identity = new GenericIdentity("Test", "Test");
var pricipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] { "Role1", "Role2" });
var cls = identity.Claims
                  .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                  .Select(c => c.Value);
foreach(var c in cls)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
Console.WriteLine("complete");
```

Answer (score 6):

In your code, you're adding the roles to the [GenericPrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.aspx) object, not the [GenericIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericidentity.aspx) object.

Therefore, the identity object doesn't have any role claims associated with it, whereas the principal object does.

---

## Getting Roles From `GenericPrincipal`

You should be able to get the roles from the `GenericPrincipal` object like so:

```cs
var identity = new GenericIdentity("Test", "Test");
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] { "Role1", "Role2" });

// We need to get the claims associated with the Principal instead of the Identity
var roles = principal.Claims
                     .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                     .Select(c => c.Value);

Console.WriteLine("Roles associated with the GenericPrincipal:");
foreach(var role in roles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(role);
}
```

> **Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCxmIR

---

## Getting Roles From `GenericIdentity`

If you need to track roles for a specific `GenericIdentity` object, you'll have to explicitly add the role claims to the instance. Then, you can get the roles from the identity object like so:

```
var roles = new[] { "Role1", "Role2" };
var identity = new GenericIdentity("Test", "Test");

// Explicitly add role Claims to the GenericIdentity
foreach (var role in roles)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
Console.WriteLine("All Claims associated with the GenericIdentity:");
foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
{
    Console.WriteLine(claim);
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, there's no "Role" claims after calling the constructor of GenericPrincipal... Any Idea ? (I do find the private property m_roles though, which contains the correct values)

Comment: Guess that's because I'm using .NET 4.x and MVC 5 :/